# Getting data from WebView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, xamarin

I have a webpage displayed inside a web view.. on the webpage the user is supposed to be selecting a date using a calendar control/datepicker and this value will go towards the server side.

How can the data  passed through a function to a server side and from server side how can i get back to application using xamarin forms

Regards
Jazzy Z

Comment: Can you be a little more specific regarding how the data is flowing here?  Is this a HTML form that's submitted to the server in some way?  Or is the app supposed to get the data and submit it on the C# side?  What are you trying to get back to the application from the server?  Is there a reason it can't be in the server's response to posting the data?

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be a web view instead of the calendar picker in Forms then take a look at [XLabs HybridWebView](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView) as it provides two-way communication between JS & C#.

Another option would be to use a date picker in Forms. If the built-in picker isn't enough you can take a look at [XLabs Calendar Control](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Calendar-Control).

The XLabs project is community project and you can either get it from NuGet (XLabs.Forms is where the Forms related items are) or copy what you need from the GitHub source.